# Is there a way to make a sized and functional FlatList inside a Modal?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Good evening!

I have been trying to create a modal with a scrollable FlatList inside, but such FlatList should have its height size reduced. The modal is going to search a wide list of airports, so basically a lot data might be shown, hence why FlatList is the best tool for this occasion. Basically, the modal screen would look like this picture below:

[image: Ideal Modal Example]

However, I can't make the scroll inside FlatList work no matter what. Here is the code, with the FlatList that is somewhat functional, but it has a warning:

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modalContainer: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(50,50,50,0.6)',
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    modalActivityContainer: {
      backgroundColor: colors.colorWhite,
      borderColor: colors.colorLightBlack,
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: 20,
      padding: props.padding ? Number(props.padding) : 10,
      maxWidth: '85%',
    },
    modalHeader: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    headerAirportModal: {
      backgroundColor: colors.colorGrey,
      borderTopRightRadius: 20,
      borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
      paddingHorizontal: 5,
      paddingVertical: 10,
      width: '100%',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    searchAirportBarContainer: {
      backgroundColor: colors.colorWhite,
      height: 40,
    },

...
    <Modal
      onRequestClose={() => props.onRequestClose()}
      animationType="fade"
      transparent
      visible={props.showModal}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => {
          props.onRequestClose();
        }}>
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View style={styles.modalActivityContainer}>

              <View style={styles.modalHeader}>
          <View style={styles.headerAirportModal}>
            <Item style={styles.searchAirportBarContainer} rounded>
              <Icon
                style={styles.iconSearchAirport}
                type="FontAwesome5"
                name="search"
              />
              <Input
                style={styles.searchAirportBarText}
                placeholderTextColor={colors.colorLightBlack}
                placeholder="Search by Airport, Country or City"
              />
            </Item>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View>
          <View style={styles.modalHeader}>
            <Grid style={styles.headerAirportModalBackground}>
              <Text style={styles.headerAirportModalText}>Latest Searches</Text>

              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.clearButtonLatestContainer}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.clearButtonAirport}>Clear</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Grid>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={{maxHeight: 250}}>
          <ScrollView>
            <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>
              <FlatList
                data={airportElements}
                renderItem={renderAirportItem}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              />
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>

        <Button
          backgroundColor={colors.colorRed}
          alignSelf="stretch"
          buttonStyle={styles.finishButton}
          onPress={() => {
            setModalSelectAirport(false);
          }}>
          Cancel
        </Button>

            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </Modal>
```

If I use the FlatList inside the ScrollView like shown above, the code works as intended. However, I got this warning:

> VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews
>   with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed
>   container instead.

Because of that, I can't use FlatList properly. Also, I have managed to make it work with `.map`, but it was advised to not use it as I am going to load a list with a lot of elements and that might cause lag.

I have managed to implement FlatList in another way like this:

```
        <View
          style={styles.airportLatestSearchListContainer}>
          <FlatList
            contentContainerStyle={styles.airportLatestSearchlist}
            data={airportElements}
            renderItem={renderAirportItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          />
        </View>
```

This, however, prevents the user to scroll. The list remains static and the user can't scroll at all.

I have tried using `{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1}` in the parent View and FlatList itself, both don't work at all, even inside the FlatList container or the style.

Can someone please help me with this one? I really appreciate the time and effort! Thanks!

Comment: use the FlatList inside the ScrollView ... It is normal for modal. Do not react to warnings VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews. But it is only for modal view. for legally yes VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews.

Comment: So is it actually okay to have a FlatList inside the ScrollView, as long as it's inside a modal window? I thought this would not allow FlatList functions such as "onEndReached" to work.